# Ignore accessibility label when selected in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

I have a button with an accessibility label, say 'start'. When user focuses on it, voice over announces its label as expected. However, voice over announces the label again, when user double taps. I want to ignore this second announcement. I have checked Spotify's app, when clicked on 'play' button, its icon and label changes to 'pause' but voice over does not announce this change. How can I achieve the same behavior?

Comment: do you have any working prototype (code) of current behavior? if "yes" - please share you code, it will be easier to find the expected solution

Comment: Yes, I have, but this is a very general behaviour. When a button is clicked, voice over announces its accessibility label, which I want to ignore.

Comment: **Why** do you want to ignore it? Spotify's App is the one not behaving correctly it should announce the change of state on press. Do not try and interfere with expected behaviour.

Comment: What wcag tags are you using on your button?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie You might be right, but we want to test both options with users and then decide. I think it is a bit subjective. Also, it announces the accessibility label even if it does not change.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I haven't heard wcag tags before but if it is accessibility properties you are asking, they are like this.

button.accessibilityLabel = "start"

button.accessibilityHint = "Starts media"

button.accessibilityTraits = [.button]

Comment: @BarışDenizSağlam you definitely need to read up on the WCAG accessibility spec here for more info: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> voice over announces the label again, when user double taps. I want to ignore this second announcement.

The fastest way to reach your goal is to **override the [accessibilityActivate](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#DefaultActivation) function** in a new button subclass:

```
class myButton: UIButton {

    override func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool {

        self.accessibilityLabel = ""

        return true
    }
}
```

Don't forget to redefine your accessibility label when the button action has lost the focus otherwise it will remain empty.
Use the [**UIAccessibilityFocus** informal protocol](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#focus-an-element) in the `myButton` class as follows for instance:

```
override open func accessibilityElementDidLoseFocus() {
    self.accessibilityLabel = "yourPreviousLabelHere"
}
```